# jQuery getscript callback not come when i call them in jQuery

Tags: html, css

in a function i call the script at runtime

```
function ShowMeYourFace() {
    $.getScript("/scripts/jtimers.js", function (data) {
 });
};
```

in the block inside of getscript i can see in firebug that they call them everytime function called but i never found that jtimer works. when i see in chrome dev tool i found a problem that 
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'everyTime' everyTime is a function in jtimer plugins.

can someone tell me how i can do this work.

Answer (score 0):

In the js file where you call the script you can only use the functions of the script in the callback.

Maybe you can post some code where you call the everyTime function?